# "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" when comparing lists (not arrays)

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the equality operator (`==`) regarding lists. When I run my script, I get an error in an `if` statement

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".

The `if` statement looks like this

```
if variable_a == variable_b:
```

I know that that this is caused by an array of boolean values being evaluated by the `if` statement, however to debug I printed the inputs to the function. I know they are from the type list.

```
print(variable_a)
print(variable_b)
```

I get an output that looks like this

```
[[1,2],3]
[3,4]
```

But then I try the following in the Console

```
[[1,2],3] == [3,4]
```

which returns False. This is not an array of boolean values so I don't know why the `if` statement fails. I am using python 3.9.

Edit: I just ran

```
print(type(variable_a))
print(type(variable_b))
```

which both returned

```
<class 'list'>
```

So I am definitely sure that I am comparing lists and not numpy arrays or pandas dataframes.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Console"?

Comment: I am using PyCharm and am using the Python Console to directly execute code

Comment: If you're getting that error you're dealing with numpy arrays, not lists.

Comment: Do you know they're of type `list` or that they print out in a form that looks like lists? What is `type(variable_a)` and `type(variable_b)`?

Comment: Those can't be lists, or you wouldn't get that error. I'm not sure what type they are, but FWIW, NumPy produces [similar errors](/q/10062954/4518341), only NumPy arrays wouldn't print like that. Please make a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for more tips. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: You are confusing built in `list` objects with `numpy.ndarray` objects

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For reference for future questions, please read [ask] and [mre]. We don't provide a debugging service; in order to explain a code behaviour, we need code **in the question itself** that we can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, to reproduce the **exact problem, directly**.

Answer (score 4):

This is a curious interaction between the built-in `list` type's comparison, and Numpy's comparison - which is implemented **by each Numpy datatype**, not just arrays.

A truly minimal example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.int64(1)
>>> [a] == [[a, a]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The comparison involves the following chain of events:

- `[a]` and `[[a, a]]` are both lists, so the list `__eq__` method is used.
- First, the identities and lengths of the lists are checked. They're separate lists of the same length, so the code can't bail out early.
- So we must compare the lists elementwise, and check that each pair is equal.
- The first elements of the lists are `a` and `[a, a]`, so we compare those.
- The call `a.__eq__([a, a])` succeeds: `a` is a Numpy scalar, and `[a, a]` is iterable, so Numpy broadcasts the comparison across the list.
- Now the overall list comparison needs to check whether the equality comparison returned a truthy result.However, the result of the `__eq__` call was a Numpy array (`array([True,  True])`), which doesn't allow conversion to boolean (i.e., the *standard* problem). So an exception is raised.

But notice:

```
>>> [a] == [[a]]
True
```

When `a` is compared to `[a]`, the resulting array has exactly one total element. Numpy treats this case specially.

```
>>> [[a]] == [[a, a]]
False
```

When `[a]` is compared to `[a, a]`, both are lists, so Numpy doesn't get to interfere yet. The list equality method is called again, and it checks the lengths of the lists first. Since the lengths differ, `False` is returned before any Numpy broadcasting can occur.

Also of note:

```
>>> [[a, a]] == [a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Even though the list is clearly "not equal to" the Numpy scalar, the list comparison operation will return `NotImplemented` rather than `False`, allowing the Numpy scalar's `__eq__` to be tried after that.

```
>>> [1] == [[a,a]]
False
```

This succeeds because the ordinary integer `1` will be compared to a list of Numpy objects, and the integer doesn't implement any broadcasting.

```
>>> [a] == [[1, 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The Numpy scalar will be compared to a list of integers, and broadcast across that; and the scalar value is indeed comparable to integer.

```
>>> [a] == [['a', 'b']]
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
False
>>> [a] == [['a', 1]]
False
>>> [a] == [[1.0, 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The current behaviour is dependent upon having a list *of numeric types*.

Comment: Meh, I'd say my `[[0,0]] == [a]` is even more minimal.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `a = np.int32(1)` to the top of this answer (or to the question, I guess), so it's what `a` is without the other answer.\

Comment: I incorporated the relevant changes while editing in some other useful information.

Comment: Another fun one: An iterable of two numeric values that doesn't fail: `[a] == [b'00']`.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't fail with `bytes` or `set`, but it does with `list`, `tuple` and - curiously - `bytearray`. The exact rule is probably in the documentation *somewhere*....

Comment: Do you know why that is? I would expect scalars to always act like scalars, so for them to do broadcasting is totally unexpected to me, but I'm not a NumPy expert. On the other hand, if it were a 0d array like `np.array(1)`, then broadcasting would make sense.

Comment: @wjandrea my first thought was "so that either the scalar or the array can be on the left-hand side". But that clearly doesn't matter, because `__eq__` will try it the other way around if the first way returns `NotImplemented`. My best guess is that they wanted the user to be able to omit, as much as possible, calls to create an array explicitly from nested lists. It seems very un-Pythonic to me that way, though. Just too... implicit.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake was that I used a `numpy.float32` instead of the normal float datatype as the values in my list. It was indeed a list, but I didn't check the datatype of the floats inside the list. If you want to recreate the error, you can do it like this

```
a = np.float32(1)
b = np.float32(2)
c = np.float32(3)
d = [[a,b],c]
e = [b,c]
d == e
```

Comment: Beside the point, but the question has ints, not floats. Were you maybe using `int32`, not `float32`?

Comment: Oh, that **is** interesting, actually. I can reproduce this problem, while there are many other similar lists that *won't* cause the problem.

Comment: Smaller case: `[[0,0]] == [np.int32(0)]`

Comment: This is really interesting. I'd be interested if anybody knows why this behavior happens. Nice find!

Comment: Since this is the actual MRE for the problem, it should be edited into the question (rather, the question edited *around* presenting that MRE) rather than being a separate answer.